# Sort enumeration values by name

Tags: java

I have enumeration values as follows.

```
public enum Types {

  Day, Night, Hello, Age, Sum;

}
```

Anyone please help me to sort this by name when i take this values to controller like

```
Types.values());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sort by what? It should already be sorted by ordinal value.

Comment: @August sort by name.

Comment: @user3914290: `Types.values()` returns an array.  Do you know how to sort an array?

Comment: `public enum Types { Age, Day, Hello, Night, Sum; }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`Arrays#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator))
with a  [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for `Types`:

```
Types[] arr = Types.values();
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Types>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Types o1, Types o2) {
         return o1.name().compareTo(o2.name());
     }
});
// arr is now [Age, Day, Hello, Night, Sum]
```

An alternate (but less maintainable) solution is to declare the enum constants in alphabetical order:

```
public enum Types {
     Age, Day, Hello, Night, Sum
}
```

Comment: Ah you beat me to it. +1 for also mentioning declaring them in alphabetical order.